# Is Array.from(arguments) an acceptable way to create an array of arguments?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

Is `Array.from(arguments)` worse in some way then `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` for creating an array of arguments? I haven't seen the former used anywhere, and the latter seems to be the standard way to create an arguments array from what I have read. Is anyone able to explain the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.from()` is the ES6 specified method of creating an Array object from any array-like object or iterable object.

```
var arr = Array.from(arguments)
```

is a text book example of what it is designed for and it is designed to replace the former work-arounds such as:

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
```

The only catch is that this is ES6 functionality and thus is present only in the newest browsers.  To use it safely across many browsers, you can either install a polyfill like the [one here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) or you can transpile your ES6 code into ES5 compatible code using something like BabelJS.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `Array.from(arg)` is a better way to do this because it is exactly what this function is supposed to do.

However, this functionality is a part of [a new standard ECMAScript 6](http://es6-features.org/). According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), it is not supported by all browsers yet.

Since it is sort of an "experimental" function, it is still not used everywhere. In the foreseeable future we will see the usage of `Array.from` everywhere.

For example, there are some good functions like:

```
var str = "abcdef";
if (str.startsWith('abc') && str.endsWith('def'))
```

However, if you open random website with this functionality, then you will see a custom own-written function which uses RegExp or `indexOf`. The reason is that all of these web-sites has been written before this standard has been introduced.

At the same time, many developers prefer to use old-style functions, because they are supported by all browsers. It is always difficult to introduce a new standard and migrate to it.